# How can I find the shortest path between specific items in a matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, shortest-path, fill

I have to find the shortest path between a '1' element of the matrix and a '2' element crossing only throw the '0' elements. I first thought of using the Lee algorithm but it would take to much space given that the matrix can have up to 101 elements.
This is an example of an input
I already know the length of the matrix.

> 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 
>   0 1 1 0 3 1 3 
>   3 3 3 3 0 0 0 
>   2 0 3 3 0 0 0 
>   2 2 0 3 0 1 1 
>   2 0 0 0 0 1 0

The output is 4 the shortest path being:

> 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 
>   0 1 1 0 3 1 3 
>   3 3 3 3 0 0 0 
>   2 0 3 3 0 0 0 
>   2 2 0 3 0 1 1 
>   2 * * * * 1 0

Comment: A* using "street" distance as the heuristic, maybe. Or Djikstra.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the problem should be solved with the filling algorithm or the algorithm of Lee.

Comment: Then use the filling algorithm.